# Do the AL PHB+1 restrictions work on the character's archetype?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, archetype

For example, I want to make Duergar bard (SCAG and PHB sources).

Later, when I get the third level, can I choose bard archetype from XGE?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## All your class option must be chosen from your PHB+1.

From the [DDAL Players Guide](http://www.dmsguild.com/m/product/208178) p.5 under Character Advancement:

> You use the options provided in your PHB+1 for advancing your character. Feats and spells gained by advancement are subject to PHB+1.

The only exception is specific campaign documentation that allows otherwise.

Comment: You may want to update this answer to state that [as of 2021](https://yawningportal.dnd.wizards.com/blog/saying-goodbye-to-the-ph1-rule/) there is no longer a PHB+1 rule.